Delete Tabs in Google Sheets by Tab-Name (begins with)
i need a solution for my plan to delete specific Tabs in my Spreadsheet.
I have some code that will create new Tabs that contain a prefix, a pipe (" | ") + Prompt input and moves it to pos 8.
After that, some of the pictures on the copy will be deleted.
Code :
function createpattern() {

if(ship =="[P] HAMMERHEAD"){
  do{
  var newPrefix = "HH"
  var newName = newPrefix+" | "+ui.prompt("Enter Ship Name").getResponseText();}
  
  while(!newName);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet().setName(newName);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(8);

  var images = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getImages();
  for (var i = 10; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].remove();}
 }


Now i need a function, that will recognize only the Tabs with " | " in its Name and deletes them after execution.
Best Regards

ship is undefined

Spreadsheet.getSheets().filter(sh => ~sh.getName().indexOf("|")).forEach(sh => Spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sh)
